# getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost error seen on launching the application in appium

Tags: android, node.js, appium

I am unable to launch the android app in device using APPIUM. Please find my code below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

    File appDir =  new File("src");
    File app = new File(appDir,"Mast_sab.apk");
           
    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME,MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"071ce659018966d9");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,"com.sabm.mast");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NEW_COMMAND_TIMEOUT,"1000");
    cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
    AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver (new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);

}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: Unhandled error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost
    at errnoException (dns.js:44:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:94:26) context: [POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.sabm.mast","app":"/Users/sudhir.pandit/Documents/workspace/Learning/src/Mast_sab.apk","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"071ce659018966d9","newCommandTime]
```

Please help with this error.

Comment: I am using MAC 10.9.4
Appium version 1.3.7

Comment: I am using MAC 10.9.4 and Appium version 1.3.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add 127.0.0.1 localhost in your host (private/etc/hosts) file and run the code

Comment: This is the correct answer! It saved my ass and worked instantly! Thanks bro! :-)

Answer (score 0):

For Linux users: If you are getting issue again even after adding localhost entry in /etc/hosts, then it might be nscd deamon is not started.